# error occurred while trying to write emails to google sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

```py
import gspread

emails = ['test@test.com' , 'test1@test1.com']


def api(key):
    gc = gspread.service_account(filename='Auth.json')
    sh = gc.open_by_key(key)
    worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(1)
    worksheet.insert_row(["Emails"], 1)
    worksheet.insert_rows(emails, 2)


api("myapi")
```

Error:
I'm unable to write list of emails to google sheet rows as i keep getting the following error:

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid value at \'data.values[0]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "test@test.com"\nInvalid value at \'data.values[1]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "test1@test1.com"', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'data.values[0]', 'description': 'Invalid value at \'data.values[0]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "test@test.com"'}, {'field': 'data.values[1]', 'description': 'Invalid value at \'data.values[1]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "test1@test1.com"'}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values of `['test@test.com' , 'test1@test1.com']` to the inserted rows.

In this case, I think that in this case, `['test@test.com' , 'test1@test1.com']` is required to be 2 dimensional array like `[['test@test.com'], ['test1@test1.com']]`. I think that the reason of error is due to this. So please modify as follows, and test it again.

#### From:

```
emails = ['test@test.com' , 'test1@test1.com']
```

#### To:

```
emails = [['test@test.com'], ['test1@test1.com']]
```

#### References:

- [insert_rows](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=insert_row#gspread.models.Worksheet.insert_rows)